# Unable to render all barcode images on print preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, barcode, jqprint

I am using Jqprint plugins for printing porpose

Code for printing barcode as

Html Code as:

```
<div class="wrapper_template" id="print_template">
   <div class="imageOutput" >
 // Code for Printing barcode for different Products  
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code as:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".print_link").click( function() {
                    $('#print_template').jqprint({ operaSupport: true });
                    return false;
                });
             });
</script>
```

But main Problem is unable to render all barcode image in print preview.
Anyone can solve this issue.
plz help me.

Comment: are the barcodes rendered as images or are they custom font-based barcodes?

Comment: Its font-based barcodes and if i try to print 50 barcode once a time then 4-5 barcode will be miss on rendering

Comment: it's going to be hard to diagnose the problem without being able to see the code and font. One issue could be that you have floats in your layout that aren't cleared, so you could try setting the barcode element style to display:block; clear:both; Also the jqprint plugin offers a parameter importCSS, you might try setting that to true along with operaSupport. If none of that helps you should attempt to print without the special font to see if the text prints at all - if not, you'll know it's more of a layout or CSS issue than a font rendering issue.

Comment: all text render but few barcode not render
i think its not problem of css because only  few barcode not render
not all barcode :)

Comment: what if you print without jqprint - just native browser print? do the barcodes all show then?

Comment: Ya it supports all print while using just shortcut ctr + p

Comment: I fixed Above Issue By Changing core file
 opt.printContainer = true;
to
 opt.printContainer = false;

Answer (score 0):

I fixed Above Issue By Changing core file

```
opt.printContainer = true;
```

to

```
opt.printContainer = false;
```